# OCamlfind build fails

Tags: macos, ocaml, ocamlfind

When I try to install `ocamlfind` using `opam install ocamlfind`, compilation fails and gives this message:

```
#=== ERROR while installing ocamlfind.1.5.5 ===================================#
# opam-version 1.2.0
# os           darwin
# command      make all
# path         /Users/MTGAP/.opam/system/build/ocamlfind.1.5.5
# compiler     system (4.02.1)
# exit-code    2
# env-file     /Users/MTGAP/.opam/system/build/ocamlfind.1.5.5/ocamlfind-21707-c61e7b.env
# stdout-file  /Users/MTGAP/.opam/system/build/ocamlfind.1.5.5/ocamlfind-21707-c61e7b.out
# stderr-file  /Users/MTGAP/.opam/system/build/ocamlfind.1.5.5/ocamlfind-21707-c61e7b.err
### stdout ###
# ...[truncated]
# ocamlc -I +compiler-libs -c fl_package_base.mli
# ocamlc -I +compiler-libs -g -c fl_package_base.ml
# ocamlc -I +compiler-libs -c findlib.mli
# ocamlc -I +compiler-libs -g -c findlib.ml
# ocamlc -I +compiler-libs -g -c fl_args.ml
# ocamlc -I +compiler-libs -a -o findlib.cma findlib_config.cmo fl_split.cmo fl_metatoken.cmo fl_meta.cmo fl_metascanner.cmo fl_topo.cmo fl_package_base.cmo findlib.cmo fl_args.cmo
# ocamlc -I +compiler-libs -g -c ocaml_args.ml
# ocamlc -I +compiler-libs -g -c frontend.ml
# ocamlc -I +compiler-libs -custom -o ocamlfind -g findlib.cma unix.cma \
#              ocaml_args.cmo frontend.cmo
### stderr ###
# ...[truncated]
# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
#   "start", referenced from:
#      implicit entry/start for main executable
#      (maybe you meant: _caml_heap_start, _caml_young_start , _caml_start_code , _caml_startup_code )
# ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
# File "_none_", line 1:
# Error: Error while building custom runtime system
# make[1]: *** [ocamlfind] Error 2
     make: *** [all] Error 2
```

According to past Stack Overflow answers, this install fails sometimes if m4 is not installed, but I have m4 installed and in my path so that's not the problem.

Comment: Did you install ocaml/opam via brew?

Comment: EdgarAroutiounian: Yes on both counts.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a problem in your system or in a package manager. First, I would suggest not to use system compiler, but make a new compiler installation from scratch:

```
opam switch install 4.02.1
eval `opam config env`
```

If this doesn't work the try to look at your compiler toolkit, and ensure that linker is from the same toolkit as a compiler (at best, all tools, should link to the default OS X toolkit)

Comment: I tried running `opam switch install 4.02.1`. It failed and said `Make sure the C compiler gcc -O is properly installed.` gcc is installed on my machine. I found some stuff online about this error message but it didn't look relevant.

Comment: is it installed using `macports`? I suggest you to install using X Code Developer tools (that actually installs llvm), since it is most robust solution. And also, are you sure, that installed gcc is visible in path, when you're invoking opam?